# Jenkins указать путь Archive the artifacts вне папки Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция

C целью обучения дома на вритуальной машине создал сервер для непрерывной интеграции с использованием **Jenkins** для компилляции **Android** проектов с применением системы сборки **gradle**.

В принципе все работает, собирается. Но есть одна проблема.
В **Jenkins** есть возможность указать путь куда будут помещены APK (в **Post-build Actions**) файлы после сборки **Archive the artifacts** сейчас там стоит путь по умолчанию

***/*.apk*.

Я бы хотел чтобы файл сборки у меня помещался в папку

*C:\Users\Serv1\Desktop\Build*

на виртуальной машине (где стоит Jenkins и происходит компилляция).

Можно ли это сделать в **Jenkins**?

И что нужно прописать в **Archive the artifacts** ?

Comment: как вариант можно юзать `maven-deploy-plugin` и указать куда, потом выполнить `deploy`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> **/*.apk.
> ```

Это не *куда*, а *что* нужно архивировать. По вышеприведённой маске будут архивированы все файлы с расширением `.apk` в текущей папке и всех вложенных, рекурсивно.

Archive the artifacts оставьте как есть, поставьте [Copy Artifacts Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin), в нем настройте копирование куда надо.

А вообще лучше сделать отдельный job с публикацией, который запускать либо вручную, либо плагином [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin), в частности сразу можно в маркет публиковать [Google Play Android Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Google+Play+Android+Publisher+Plugin)...

Смысл в том, что генерация apk и публикация - два разных задания, которые могут упасть независимо друг от друга. И если, например, apk генерится, а публикация не работает, то job публикации можно будет запустить дополнительно, не пересобирая приложение.

Comment: Восстановил, т.к. ответ верный как по практическим рекомендациям так и по сути. Чуток дополнил. Надеюсь, вы не против. Если что — пишите, перепубликую анонимно.